# Xamarin - phone call events / state

Tags: xamarin

I'm very new to Xamarin and mobile development, but have an experience with C#.
Following is my attempt to take some code from the web and adjusting it to Xamarin.
The code fails on exception, while placing a call.
I, actually, can't reach breakpoints in my CallReceiver / PhonecallReceiver classes.
I'm running VS2017 community, API23, arm phone.
What I'm missing?

MainActivity:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Telephony;
using Java.Lang;
using String = System.String;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Java.Util;
using Javax.Security.Auth;

namespace CallManipulation
{
    public abstract class PhonecallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
    private static CallState lastState = CallState.Idle;
    private static DateTime callStartTime;
    private static bool isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;


    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action.Equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
        {
            savedNumber = intent.Extras.GetString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else
        {
            String stateStr = intent.Extras.GetString(TelephonyManager.ExtraState);
            String number = intent.Extras.GetString(TelephonyManager.ExtraIncomingNumber);
            CallState state = CallState.Idle;

            if (stateStr.Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle))
            {
                state = CallState.Idle;
            }
            else if (stateStr.Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateOffhook))
            {
                state = CallState.Offhook;
            }
            else if (stateStr.Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging))
            {
                state = CallState.Ringing;
            }

            OnCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, DateTime start) { }
    protected virtual void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, DateTime start) { }
    protected virtual void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, DateTime start, DateTime end) { }
    protected virtual void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, DateTime start, DateTime end) { }
    protected virtual void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, DateTime start) { }

        public void OnCallStateChanged(Context context, CallState state, string number)
        {
            if (lastState == state)
                return;
            switch (state)
            {
                case CallState.Ringing:
                    isIncoming = true;
                    callStartTime = new DateTime().Date;
                    savedNumber = number;
                    onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                    break;
                case CallState.Offhook:
                    if (lastState != CallState.Ringing)
                    {
                        isIncoming = false;
                        callStartTime = new DateTime().Date;
                        onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                    }
                    break;
                case CallState.Idle:
                    if (lastState == CallState.Ringing)
                        onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                    else if (isIncoming)
                        onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new DateTime().Date);
                    else
                        onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new DateTime().Date);
                    break;
            }
            lastState = state;
        }
    }

    public class CallReceiver : PhonecallReceiver
    {
        protected override void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, string number, DateTime start)
        {
        }

        protected override void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, string number, DateTime start)
        {
        }

        protected override void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, string number, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
        }

        protected override void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, string number, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
        }

        protected override void onMissedCall(Context ctx, string number, DateTime start)
        {
        }
    }

    [Activity(Label = "CallManipulation", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="CallManipulation.CallManipulation" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
  <application android:label="CallManipulation">
    <!--This part is inside the application-->
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Output window:

08-01 15:53:29.279 D/Mono    ( 2601): [0x9f7fd930] worker starting
08-01 15:53:29.308 D/Mono    ( 2601): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
08-01 15:53:29.308 D/Mono    ( 2601): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
08-01 15:53:29.308 D/Mono    ( 2601): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
08-01 15:53:29.308 D/Mono    ( 2601): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601): Process: CallManipulation.CallManipulation, PID: 2601
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver CallManipulation.CallManipulation.CallReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "CallManipulation.CallManipulation.CallReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/CallManipulation.CallManipulation-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/CallManipulation.CallManipulation-1/lib/arm, /data/app/CallManipulation.CallManipulation-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2706)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "CallManipulation.CallManipulation.CallReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/CallManipulation.CallManipulation-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/CallManipulation.CallManipulation-1/lib/arm, /data/app/CallManipulation.CallManipulation-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2701)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     ... 8 more
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CallManipulation.CallManipulation.CallReceiver
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):         ... 10 more
08-01 15:53:29.316 E/AndroidRuntime( 2601):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Comment: Please post a Stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: I would start by looking at some examples to implement receiver with correct attribute and intent filters https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/299/notification-if-someone-calls

Comment: Hi,
Thank you, guys, for taking a look on it.

I've added 'Output' window trace in the body of my question (stack is not available, as I can't reach my breakpoints).